# Using non-tensorflow operations in a custom Keras regularizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a custom Keras activity regularizer with a set of rather specific operations, including, but not limited to, PCA on the outputs. The regularizing code is working separately and is written on Numpy and sklearn. Trying to implement the same code as a custom Keras regularizer I've encountered numerous issues related to Tensors not being computed; from other information I managed to gather, I've got the impression that the regularizing function *compiles* during the model definition.

- Does it mean that I can't cast Tensors to Numpy arrays, then use Numpy operations in the regularizer?
- Is it correct that all values featured in my regularizer must be either pre-computed or Tensors?
- Exactly what can I use in the regularizer? Can I, for example, use a index variable calculated on the data received, as suggested [here](https://tomaxent.com/2018/01/17/PCA-With-Tensorflow/) (reduce implementation)?

Comment: Tensorflow needs to build a differentiable graph of tensor operations, because they are using automatic differentiation. Since regularization is typically added as an extra penalty to the loss function, your regularization function needs to be a function of differentiable tensor operations as well.

Comment: Does that pretty much mean I simply can't do it? Since not even all Tensorflow functions (`tf.size` for instance) are differentiable, I can't see how do I pick up differentiable operations exclusively to build the regularizer I need. Is there another framework that would allow me to do it?

Comment: I don't know, which operations you are explicetly using. You could try to approximate your non differentiable functions with differentiable ones. There are some autodiff libs but I am not sure if you can combine them with the DL frameworks. Anyway I don't think, that they will do, what you expect them to do. You could use numerical approximation of gradient via `(f(x+e)-f(x+e))/(2e)`, but I can't say, whether that will work or not, because it may lead to bad behaviour due to bad approximations.